# LCD(20x4) module with 2 sensors

Tags: bmp180

I'm using DHT22 and BMP180 to mesure temperature, pressure and humidity. I connected DHT22 to pin1(3.3V), pin7(GPIO4) and pin9(GND); and BMP108 to pin3(GPIO2), pin5(GPIO3), pin6(GND), pin17(3.3V).
I want to connect 20x4 LCD display, but I've already used both 3.3V pins, I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVdSc8VYVBM) tutorial. So if I put resistor to 5V pin and convert it to 3.3V would that work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for total available amperage, there is no limit to the number of things you can attach to one 3.3V pin.  They are both connected together in parallel anyway; having 2 is just a convenience.  If you have this inside a case of some sort, an easy solution is to get a small breadboard, cut it in half, and attach a 3.3V pin to the + rail.  You now have 30 parallel 3.3V slots.

Alternately you could solder multiple wires together on one lead, etc.

Comment: So I can connect N number of sensors to one 3.3V pin?

Comment: Yes, although again, there's not unlimited current, so N cannot extend into infinity.   Unlike the 5V pins the 3.3V power is regulated; I think the official maximum is 50 mA but the real maximum may be several times that.   A few sensors like this + a segment LCD should be fine I think, if the display definitely can't use 5V.